# Laravel 5 Eloquent, How to set cast attribute dynamically

Tags: php, laravel, casting, laravel-5, eloquent

In laravel 5.1 there is new feature called Attribute Casting, well documented at here :
http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

My question is, it is possible to make attribute casting dynamically ?

for example, I have a table with columns :

```
id | name          | value       | type    |
1  | Test_Array    | [somearray] | array   |
2  | Test_Boolean  | someboolean | boolean |
```

it is possible to set `value` attribute cast, depends on `type` field, that work both in write(create/update) and fetch ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to overwrite Eloquent model's **getCastType()** method in your model class:

```
protected function getCastType($key) {
  if ($key == 'value' && !empty($this->type)) {
    return $this->type;
  } else {
    return parent::getCastType($key);
  }
}
```

You'll also need to add **value** to **$this->casts** so that Eloquent recognizes that field as **castable**. You can put the default cast there that will be used if you didn't set **type**.

**Update:**

The above works perfectly when reading data from the database. When writing data, you have to make sure that **type** is set before **value**. There are 2 options:

1. Always pass an array of attributes where **type** key comes before **value** key - at the moment model's **fill()** method respects the order of keys when processing data, but it's not future-proof.
2. Explicitely set **type** attribute before setting other attributes. It can be easily done with the following code:

   ```
   $model == (new Model(['type' => $data['type']))->fill($data)->save();
   ```

Comment: Ah, I like that. Much better than my options. Time for sleep.

Comment: yeah looks great. let me try this first.

Comment: Cool :) I havven't tested this exact code, so let me know if you have any issues and I'll get that working for you

Comment: I am working now, hehehe.

what exactly mean about `$this->type` ?
when I try to fetch data using `find()` and do `dd($this->type)` inside the function. there is nothing. :/

Comment: I can see type column in your table - this I assume is used to determine the type of cast, right?

Comment: oh yes my bad, your code is work on fetch data, but doesn't work when write (create or update). because `$this->type` is from fetched data.

Comment: Looking at Eloquent model's code there is no other way than making sure that type is set before the value - all methods involved in casting have access only to the current attribute being cast, not to the whole change set. But create/update respects the order in the $attributes array when setting values so you could use that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85271/discussion-between-antoniputra-and-jedrzej-kurylo).

Comment: very nice chat @jedrzej.kurylo you save my day :D

Comment: Plus one for being 100% copy-paste-compatible with my model :D

Answer (score 3):

Some of the answers here are really overthinking things, or they're subtly wrong.

The principle is simply to set the $casts property before you need it, eg. before writing or reading properties to the database.

In my case I needed to use a configured column name and cast it. Because PHP doesn't allow function calls in constant expressions, it can't be set in the class declaration, so I just declared my column/property's cast in my model's constructor.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model; 

class MyModel extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        // we can't call a function in a class constant expression or
        // we'll get 'Constant expression contains invalid operations'
        // config('my-table.array-column.name') => 'array', // this won't work
    ];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->casts = array_merge(
            $this->casts, // we can still use $casts above if desired
            [
                // my column name is configured so it isn't known at
                // compile-time so I have to set its cast run-time;
                // the model's constructor is as good a place as any
                config('my-table.array-column.name') => 'array',
            ]
        );

        parent::__construct(...func_get_args());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `$casts` attribute it used whenever you access a field, not when it is fetched from the database. Therefore, you can update the `$casts` attribute after the model has been populated, and it should work fine whenever you access the `value` field. You just need to figure out how to update the `$casts` attribute when the `type` field is changed.

One potential option would be to override the `fill()` method so that it calls the parent `fill()` method first, and then updates the `$casts` attribute with the data in the `type` field.

Another potential option would be to abuse the mutator functionality, and create a mutator on the `type` field, so that whenever it changes, it would update the `$casts` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In my situation (storing some sort of general settings under `Laravel 8.x`), I ended up using [an accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) on the `value` attribute. Something like next:

```php
/**
 * Get the value attributte.
 *
 * @param  string  $value
 * @return mixed
 */
 public function getValueAttribute($value)
 {
    // Workaround to auto cast the value attribute when accesing it, using
    // the hint provided in the type attribute.

    if (in_array($this->type, ['bool', 'boolean'])) {
        return filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOL);
    } else if (in_array($this->type, ['int', 'integer'])) {
        $v = filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
        return $v === false ? 0 : $v;
    } else if ($this->type == 'float') {
        $v = filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
        return $v === false ? 0 : $v;
    } else {
        return $value;
    }
}
```

Just sharing another alternative...