# Storing a dynamic array and string

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a website where users can transform a text document and save it to what I call a `field`. One text document can have a dynamic amount of fields, thus making it hard for me to create a relational database design.

Consider below setup.

My model `Field.php` have below `fields` table.

```
id | name       | type
-----------------------
1  | invoice_no | text
2  | addresses  | table
```

I also have a table where I save the field result for a specific document:

On model `Result` I have a `$casts` type:

```php
protected $casts = [
    'content' => 'array'
];
```

This is my `results` table:

```
id | field_id | document_id | content
-------------------------
1  | 1        |  32         | #81724
2  | 2        |  32         | [{"0": "Parkway", "1": "Broadway"}, {"0": "Avenue St.", "1": "Main St."}]
```

The data from the table is simply being read from a `.json` file.

Now ultimately, when all fields for a specific document (in this case `32`) is entered in my database, I would like to send a webhook with the field data, such as:

```
{
  "invoice_no":"#81724",
  "addresses": [{
       "0": "Parkway",
       "1": "Broadway"
   },{
       "0": "Avenue St.",
       "1": "Main St."
   }]
}
```

So above is what I have visioned - but I am not sure if this is the best approach?

1. The `$casts` on my Model returns the `content` as an array - but as you can see for `results.content`, it can be both a string and an array.
2. How should I store the content in my database? I cannot make the column as a `JSON` type, if I also want to store strings.

## Another approach?

Would it make more sense to have two columns on the `results` table for the content, so it becomes:

```sql
id | field_id | document_id | text    | array
----------------------------------------------
1  | 1        |  32         | #81724  | NULL
2  | 2        |  32         | NULL    | [{"0": "Parkway", "1": "Broadway"}, {"0": "Avenue St.", "1": "Main St."}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach is fine, you need to override the getCastType method as mentioned as an answer for the following question [Laravel 5 Eloquent, How to set cast attribute dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847050/laravel-5-eloquent-how-to-set-cast-attribute-dynamically). So you can adopt different types. For the field data type depends on the maximum expected length, so it may be either  a `Varchar` or `Text` (assuming that all data types you store in this field are text based)

### Update:

assuming that you expecting two types `string` and `table`, and you want the `table` type to be cast to `array`, you may override the `getCastType` method as following:

```
protected function getCastType($key) {
      if ($key == 'content' && !empty($this->field->type)) {
        switch($this->field->type) {
            case 'table':
                return 'array';
            break;
            case 'string':
                return 'string';
            break;
            default:
                return parent::getCastType($key);
        }
      } else {
        return parent::getCastType($key);
      }
    }
```

and to be able to get access to the field type using `$this->field->type`, you need to implement the relationship in the result model as following:

```
public function field() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Field');
}
```

All the Best

Comment: Thank you for that link - was not aware that you can set the cast type dynamically. Would it be an option to say that if the `$field->type === 'table'` then the cast should be `array`, and if not, it should be a `string`?

Comment: my pleasure, yes you can say `$field->type === 'table'` then the cast should be array

Answer (score 0):

By far the easiest and ugliest way to do this is to add a BLOB column to your database (tables) and just store the JSON there.

What you could do is send the results from the table as arrays to the backend and process it there using `[]` on the names of your input fields.

Please post how you get the data from the table so I can assist you further and someone will probably tell you how you can get this working.

Comment: Updated my question - the data (both string and text) is coming from `.json` files. So for each field, I read the content of a json file and saves the content to my database. If needed, I can change the structure/content of the json files.